# Why does Hazelcast not show entry in the Map when added via CachePut/Cacheable

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast, spring-cache

I have a use case where by the @CachePut annotation adds an entry to the cache, and I have to retrieve it manually (via code).

I can see that the total backup count gives me 1 as the number of entries, but all the maps give me the size as 0. So, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here's my code

HazelcastConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class HazelcastConfig {

    @Bean
    public Config hazelcastConf() {
        Config c = new Config()
                .setInstanceName("hazelcast-instance")
                .addMapConfig(
                        new MapConfig()
                                .setName("testmap")
                                .setEvictionConfig(
                                        new EvictionConfig()
                                                .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                                                .setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.PER_NODE)
                                                .setSize(1000)
                                )
                                .setTimeToLiveSeconds(500000)
                );
        c.getNetworkConfig().getRestApiConfig().setEnabled(true);
        c.getNetworkConfig().getRestApiConfig().enableGroups(RestEndpointGroup.DATA);
        return c;
    }
}
```

TestServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    @CachePut(value = "testmap", key="1")
    public String getId() {

        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println("-------INSIDE getId-------");
        String id = null;
        CBObject obj = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:3000/testCB", CBObject.class);
        if (null != obj && null != obj.getId()) {
            id = String.valueOf(obj.getId());
        }
        System.out.println("-------- EXIT getId-------");
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        return id;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

TestController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class TestController {


    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @GetMapping("/testCB")
    public ResponseEntity<?> doCB() {
        Map<String, String> resp = new HashMap<>();
        String id = testService.getId();
        if (null != id) {
            resp.put("id", id);
        }
        Config config = new HazelcastConfig().hazelcastConf();
        System.out.println(config.getMapConfig("testmap").getTotalBackupCount()); // 1
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName(config.getInstanceName());
        System.out.println(hz.getReplicatedMap("testmap").size()); // 0
        System.out.println(hz.getMap("testmap").size()); // 0
        System.out.println(hz.getMultiMap("testmap").size()); // 0

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(resp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you explicitly enabled caching using the `@EnableCaching` annotation ([Ref Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotation-enable), [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html))?

Also, see the [guidance](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching) from Spring Boot in the Ref Doc on Caching if you are using Spring Boot.

Furthermore, when using Spring Boot, you can either add the command-line switch `--debug` to your launch command or set the `debug` property to `true` in Spring Boot *application.properties* to get output from the Auto-configuration that has been applied. In particular you will want to see that the [`CacheAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/CacheAutoConfiguration.html) class has been processed.

If you are NOT using Spring Boot, then in addition to the `@EnableCaching` annotation, you will also need to explicitly declare a `CacheManager` bean, such as:

```java
@Bean
HazelcastCacheManager cacheManager(HazelcastInstance hazelcaseInstance) {
  return new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance);
}
```

This will require the `com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring` JAR dependency on your runtime classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

For [example](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-boot-hazelcast-caching-example/blob/main/pom.xml#L66-L71).

> NOTE: Do you not confuse the [`HazelcastCacheManager`](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/spring/cache/HazelcastCacheManager.html) Spring Cache Abstraction `CacheManager` implementation, which requires the `hazelcast-spring` JAR and is required by Spring's Cache Abstraction either with or without Spring Boot, with Hazelcast's standard [`HazelcastCacheManager`](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/cache/HazelcastCacheManager.html). These 2 classes are not the same thing.

Alternatively, you could also use Hazelcast as a JCache caching provider implementation in either Spring Framework or Spring Boot. The core Spring Framework offers [support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/jcache/package-summary.html) for using JCache as well. When using Spring Boot, you will need to specify the JCache cache provider type for Hazelcast (i.e. Embedded or Client/Server). I will leave this as an exercise for you to figure out.

Lastly, I recently built an [example](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-boot-hazelcast-caching-example/tree/main/src/main/java/org/example/spring/boot/cache/hazelcast) for my own testing purposes using Hazelcast as a caching provider in Spring Framework's Cache Abstraction using Spring Boot, if you would like to take a look.

Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Turns out, I had to add a cache manager bean, even though I was using spring boot and it worked like a charm. Thanks for your help.